# Pasar imagen tipo String a JasperReport como parámetro

Tags: java, java-ee, jasper-reports, openxava

Estoy trabajando con *MySQL*,  *Java 8*, *JasperReport* y *OpenXava*. Lo que hago es recuperar una imagen que guardo en base de datos con el tipo `CLOB` y la extraigo como `String`.

Esta variable la mando como parámetro de la siguiente forma:

```
parametros.put("imagen1", new ByteArrayInputStream(datos.getImagen1().getBytes()));
```

Convirtiendo la imagen del tipo `String` a un `inputStream`. En *JasperReport* pongo un elemento tipo `image` pasándole `$P{imagen}` y también configuro que utilice cache.

Además este parámetro que recibe, le especifico que va a ser un `inputStream`.

Sin embargo siempre me salta este error:

```
GRAVE: Image read failed.
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Image read failed.
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRJdk14ImageReader.readImage(JRJdk14ImageReader.java:73)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRImageLoader.loadAwtImageFromBytes(JRImageLoader.java:167)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRImageRenderer.getImage(JRImageRenderer.java:407)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRImageRenderer.getDimension(JRImageRenderer.java:482)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillImage.fitImage(JRFillImage.java:747)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillImage.resolveElement(JRFillImage.java:911)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElement.performDelayedEvaluation(JRFillElement.java:983)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElement.resolveElement(JRFillElement.java:1085)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.ElementEvaluationAction.execute(JRBaseFiller.java:2436)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.resolveBoundElements(JRBaseFiller.java:1620)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.resolveReportBoundElements(JRBaseFiller.java:1647)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillSummary(JRVerticalFiller.java:1077)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportEnd(JRVerticalFiller.java:319)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:158)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:939)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:871)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:114)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:653)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:969)
    at org.openxava.actions.JasperMultipleReportBaseAction.execute(JasperMultipleReportBaseAction.java:203)
    at org.openxava.actions.JasperConcatReportBaseAction.execute(JasperConcatReportBaseAction.java:91)
    at org.openxava.datos.actions.Imprimir.execute(Imprimir.java:146)
    at org.openxava.controller.ModuleManager.executeAction(ModuleManager.java:535)
    at org.openxava.controller.ModuleManager.executeAction(ModuleManager.java:443)
    at org.openxava.controller.ModuleManager.execute(ModuleManager.java:404)
    at org.apache.jsp.xava.execute_jsp._jspService(execute_jsp.java:256)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:720)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:584)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:523)
    at org.openxava.web.servlets.Servlets.getURIAsStream(Servlets.java:72)
    at org.openxava.web.dwr.Module.getURIAsStream(Module.java:214)
    at org.openxava.web.dwr.Module.request(Module.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.directwebremoting.impl.ExecuteAjaxFilter.doFilter(ExecuteAjaxFilter.java:34)
    at org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultRemoter$1.doFilter(DefaultRemoter.java:428)
    at org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultRemoter.execute(DefaultRemoter.java:431)
    at org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultRemoter.execute(DefaultRemoter.java:283)
    at org.directwebremoting.servlet.PlainCallHandler.handle(PlainCallHandler.java:52)
    at org.directwebremoting.servlet.UrlProcessor.handle(UrlProcessor.java:101)
    at org.directwebremoting.servlet.DwrServlet.doPost(DwrServlet.java:146)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.jasig.cas.client.util.AssertionThreadLocalFilter.doFilter(AssertionThreadLocalFilter.java:40)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.jasig.cas.client.util.HttpServletRequestWrapperFilter.doFilter(HttpServletRequestWrapperFilter.java:62)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractTicketValidationFilter.doFilter(AbstractTicketValidationFilter.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.jasig.cas.client.authentication.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:93)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter.doFilter(SingleSignOutFilter.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema posiblemente sea debido al trato que le das a los bytes como si fuera una cadena. Puede que porque intente parsear utf-8, o porque cambie la 'endianness' (little-endian vs big-endian), o por muchos otros motivos.

La solución es simplemente utilizar binarios en todo momento y no String. En la entidad Java deberías utilizar un campo byte[] directamente, y en MySQL el campo debería ser BLOB, MEDIMUMBLOB, o LONGBLOB, según necesites almacenar un máximo de 64KiB, 16MiB, o 4GiB, respectivamente. Puedes ver más información sobre estos tipos de datos en https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-requirements.html

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, he cambiado el tipo a byte[], pero sige saltando el error.
el parametro ahora lo paso asi: parametros.put("imagen1", new ByteArrayInputStream(datos.getImagen1());
Y en el informe todo sigue igual...¿deberia cambiar algo mas?

Comment: Lo primero que deberías hacer es averiguar cuál es exactamente el fallo, para lo cual puedes probar cada parte por separado. Recupera una imagen de BD y guárdala en un fichero a ver si efectivamente es una imagen, lee un fichero que contenga una imagen y envía los bytes al report. Intentar solucionar un problema cuando ni siquiera sabes en qué parte del código está el problema es muy difícil para cualquiera.

Comment: El problema principal está en la base de datos, que debería tener un BLOB y no un CLOB/TEXT. De todas maneras, tal como dice @SJuan76 deberías depurar y ver dónde está el problema.

Comment: @SJuan76 Tienes razon, y eso hacia, a la proxima no tendre tanta prisa en responder y antes probare todo lo que pruebo mientras espero una respuesta.
Efectivamente, al cambiar la estructura, estaba guardando como String aún, pero ya lo e modificado y revisado todo, ahora si funciona.
Gracias por vuestra ayuda y consejos SJuan76 y Calabacin